# как вырезать слова из списка сказанные пользователем

Tags: python

нужна помощь! не получается сделать что бы сказанное пользователем слово из списка а далее кого нужно найти вырезалось и оставалось только имя кого надо найти

пример: кто такой путин

вырезает 'путин'
и ищет в википедии

вот мой код

cf.py

```
commands = {
             "who": ['кто такой' , 'кто это' , 'найди кто такой']
    }
```

fn.py

```
def who(voice,talk):
    e_who = ''.join(['who'])
    if e_who in voice:
        Q = voice.replace(e_who , '').strip()
        wikipedia.set_lang('ru')
        A = wikipedia.search(Q)
        talk(A)
```

при таком коде ничего не работает но и ошибок тоже нет
помогите как решить?

Comment: Я надеюсь, что вы не забыли вызвать функцию, которую определили. Просто этот вызов вы решили не показывать, что-бы немного усложнить нам процесс поиска ответа на ваш вопрос.

Comment: я вызвал же функцию но всё равно ни чего не происходит

Comment: Ткните в оператор в вашем пример, где вы вызываете функцию?